# ArrayList Recursion bheaviour

Tags: java, algorithm, object, recursion, arraylist

I am doing a problem in which print unique path from (0,0) to (row-1,cols-1)..
but having difficulty to understand bheaviour of arraylist .please explain this bheaviour and different way to do it correct way.

```java
static void distnctpaths(int maze[][], int i, int j, int r, int c, ArrayList < Integer > path) {

    if (i == r && j == c) {
        path.add(maze[i][j]);
        System.out.println(path);
        return;
    }

    if (i == r + 1 || j == c + 1)
        return;

    path.add(maze[i][j]);

    distnctpaths(maze, i, j + 1, r, c, path);
    distnctpaths(maze, i + 1, j, r, c, path);


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int maze[][] = {
        { 1, 2, 3 },
        { 4, 5, 6 },
        { 7, 8, 9 },
    };
    ArrayList < Integer > path = new ArrayList < > ();

    distnctpaths(maze, 0, 0, 2, 2, path);
}
```

> wrong output

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 5, 6, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 5, 6, 9, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 5, 6, 9, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 5, 6, 9, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 5, 6, 9, 8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9]
```

> correct output(for reference)

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 9]
[1, 2, 5, 6, 9]
[1, 2, 5, 8, 9]
[1, 4, 5, 6, 9]
[1, 4, 5, 8, 9]
[1, 4, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains a simple logical error. When you add an location in the path, you do not remove it after being done with it.

---

### Code

```
public static void distinctPaths(int[][] maze, int i, int j, int r , int c, ArrayList<Integer> path)
{
    if(i == r && j == c)
    {
        path.add(maze[i][j]);
        System.out.println(path);

        path.remove(path.size()-1);
        return ;
    }

    if (i == r+1 || j == c+1) return;

    path.add(maze[i][j]);
    distinctPaths(maze,i,j+1, r, c, path);
    distinctPaths(maze, i+1, j, r,c,path);
    path.remove(path.size()-1);
}
```

---

### Improvements

In the above, there is an extra `path.add(index)` and `path.remove(index)`. Here is the same code, a bit modified so it is more concise and eliminates repetition of statement.

```
public static void distinctPaths(int[][] maze, int i, int j, int r , int c, ArrayList<Integer> path)
{
    if (i == r+1 && j == c) System.out.println(path);
    if (i == r+1 || j == c+1) return;

    path.add(maze[i][j]);

    distinctPaths(maze,i,j+1, r, c, path);
    distinctPaths(maze, i+1, j, r,c,path);

    path.remove(path.size()-1);
}
```

It produces the same output but its shorter and better.

---

### Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 9]
[1, 2, 5, 6, 9]
[1, 2, 5, 8, 9]
[1, 4, 5, 6, 9]
[1, 4, 5, 8, 9]
[1, 4, 7, 8, 9]
```

---

This will solve your problem. *I have not provided any dry run to show what the significance of `path.remove(index)` is*. You can run a debugger to do so yourself. If you still face any problems, do comment. I will edit my answer to help you.

Comment: thanks for such a detailed and awesome answer.. i have one more question when i pass path as new ArrayList<>(path) in function call  distinctPaths. it also give correct answer can you explain me this case in answer.

Comment: Yes I can. There is nothing special happening here. You are using previous array list to construct a new array list. You are using `ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)` constructor of array list. Here is a link to the official Javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: This will seem confusing if you do not know `generics`.